# Setting the thumbnail for safari web previews

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I view iCloud.com in my safari top sites, it always always has the same thumbnail.

[image]

I'm wondering how I could programmatically do the same for my website.

Comment: Do you mean how the pictures are all recent, relavent, snapshots of the page you are looking at?

Comment: Yes and no.  I'm wondering why iCloud has the same thumbnail every single time, even when I visit iCloud from a different computer.

Comment: @rlemon notice how the one on the right is the iCloud logo and not a snapshot of a page.  That is the question, the ability to set the displayed image instead of a page screenshot.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I see this JavaScript:

```
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.loadPurpose === "preview") {
        window.location.href = "https://www.icloud.com/topsites_preview/"
    };
```

Comment: +1 Nice find!  I was digging through this lightly myself but missed it.

Comment: Has anyone out there actually seen this work for any site besides iCloud?

Comment: This is missing a `)` if anyone isn't seeing it work. `if(window.navigator && window.navigator.loadPurpose === "preview") { window.location.href = "https://www.icloud.com/topsites_preview/" };`